# Vaadin 7 get screen Width

Tags: exception, get, resolution, vaadin

I am getting a UnsatisfiedLinkError exception when I am trying to get the screen Width like this:

```
int screenWidth = BrowserInfo.get().getScreenWidth();
```

The exception is thrown at BrowserInfo.getBrowserString():

```
Feb 25, 2013 2:03:40 PM com.vaadin.server.DefaultErrorHandler doDefault
SEVERE: 
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: com.vaadin.client.BrowserInfo.getBrowserString()Ljava/lang/String;
at com.vaadin.client.BrowserInfo.getBrowserString(Native Method)
at com.vaadin.client.BrowserInfo.<init>(BrowserInfo.java:76)
at com.vaadin.client.BrowserInfo.get(BrowserInfo.java:67)
at com.vaadin.client.BrowserInfo.<clinit>(BrowserInfo.java:56)
at layoutHandler.MainLayoutHanlder.setCssClasses(MainLayoutHanlder.java:34)
```

Is this a Vaadin 7 bug, or am I just using the BrowserInfo class wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Call `Page.getCurrent().getBrowserWindowWidth()` instead.

`BrowserInfo` is a client class, you should not use this in your server side classes. I would avoid putting the client libraries on the class path at all. `getBrowserWindowWidth` is native because that's the GWT compiler's way to bridge into JavaScript code. If you look at the source, the JavaScript code is in a specially formatted comment.